# Contains within List of doubles

Tags: c#, list, double, contains

Im using visual studio Immediate Window to check the content of my List. This is what I can see:

```
found_numbers
Count = 36
    [0]: 50,82
    [1]: 3358
    [2]: 954
    [3]: 5571
    [4]: 3142
    [5]: 700
    [6]: 322
    [7]: 402
    [8]: 1231
    [9]: 4118
    [10]: 4532
    [11]: 0
    [12]: 0
    [13]: 3101
    [14]: 18
    [15]: 0
    [16]: 0
    [17]: 8896
    [18]: 0
    [19]: 4,01
    [20]: 19,5
    [21]: 0,78
    [22]: 20,28
    [23]: 10
    [24]: 27,76
    [25]: 2,78
    [26]: 30,54
    [27]: 4648
    [28]: 508
    [29]: 1,51
    [30]: 4648
    [31]: 508
    [32]: 1,51
    [33]: 0,28
    [34]: 0,28
    [35]: 0,56
```

Then I check the value of my two variables

```
total1
50,82
total3
20,28
```

In the last step, I want to see if my list contains those values and this is my output:

```
found_numbers.Contains(total1)
false
found_numbers.Contains(total3)
true
```

Im really confused about this behaviour as the both numbers are into the the given list. Why could this be happening? Edit: both **total1** and **total3** are type double.

Comment: Doubles are tricky to compare due to floating point issues. Can you use Decimals instead?

Comment: Since those are `double` values then it's possible that the two "50.82" values are not exactly the same especially if either one was calculated due to floating point numbers not being precise.  Typically what you want to do is check if floating point number are within a delta of each other.

Comment: Check *exact* `double` values: `found_numbers[0].ToString("R")` and `total1.ToString("R");` you can well find that some of `50,82` values are actually `50,820000000001` or `50.819999999999998` and that's why you have `found_numbers.Contains(total1) == false`

Comment: Do you assign the variable like `total1 = 50.82` or `total1 = found_numbers[0]` ? The former is likely to not produce the exact same number as in the list.

Comment: If these are meant to be currency amounts, then I agree with @TaW that you should use `decimal` instead.

Comment: The 50.82 was result of rounding operation. I checked later and, as you suggested, the numbers weren't completely equals. Changing it to decimal did the trick

Comment: Are you on .NET Framework or on .NET? In the former, there are fourteen different `double` values that might correspond to the string `"50,82"`, the smallest of them being `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(4632349096467717154L)`, and the largest being `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(4632349096467717167L)`. The difference in .NET is that the default is to show many decimals, so that you see a difference, and only by saying `.ToString("G15")` or similar can you get the previous behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we do computation with `double` we get *rounding* errors, and that's why instead of `50,82` we actually have `50,82000000001` or `50,81999999998`. All these values are usually *represented* being *rounded* as `50,82` and we have strange `found_numbers.Contains(total1) == false`. To get *exact* `double` value use `R` format;

```
found_numbers[0].ToString("R")
total1.ToString("R")
```

try these representations and you'll see the diffrence. If you want to get rid of rounding problems you can:

1. Switch from `double` to `decimal` (esp. if values have *fixed* decimal point, e.g. if values are currencies)
2. Use *tolerance* when comparing:

```
//TODO: put the right value here
double tolerance = 1e-8;

bool found = found_numbers.Any(item => Math.Abs(item - total1) <= tolerance);
```

Comment: Note that _some_ of this depends on the .NET version. In the .NET Framework (like .NET Framework 4.8 and earlier), something like `(25.0 / 3.0).ToString()` would produce `"8,33333333333333"`, hiding some of the precision (the comma depends on the current culture). However in .NET Core starting from .NET Core 3.0, and therefore also in .NET 5, .NET 6, and so forth, the same expression `(25.0 / 3.0).ToString()` gives the longer string `"8,333333333333334"`, so you do not have to pass the `"R"` format string in that case. I speculate whether the asker is on .NET Framework.